# What class is best to use as a popup in an iPhone?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiactionsheet

I've heard that UIActionSheet is best to use as a popup for the iPhone, but I do not know whether apple will like the following use of the class:

I do not wish to present the user with a choice, but rather notify them when the app looses connectivity.  I would love to use a native apple class... is there anything better than the UIActionSheet?

Am I allowed to use the UIActionSheet in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is UIAlertView. It's usually used to provide informational updates to the user, or in your case, connectivity updates, and if need be provide options

[UIAlertView Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/)

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine (other apps have notices when connectivity is lost) but beware you don't punish the user for a flapping network connection on a phone that's going out and coming back every few minutes.